# Buffer divider staggered upon split window and scroll

Tags: window-splitting, scrolling

Whenever I split windows or scroll with a split window, the buffer dividers and text end up staggered horizontally.

Here is a screenshot of a file without the split window or issue shown.
[image: One file no issue]

And here is a picture of what happens when I C-x 3 to split the window.

[image]

The same file is displayed on both sides.

The issue also occurs whenever I scroll in the file in the right buffer with the scroll feature, using C-n, or using C-v.

The issue occurs regardless of the two files being the same. The issue is resolved when I C-l.

Is there a way to avoid is issue in the first place?

EDIT:

I am running emacs on a remote server which I ssh into using the Terminal app version 2.8.2 in macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.

I have tried using iTerm2 build 3.3.12 and the problem still occurs.

In both cases I am running GNU Emacs 26.1 (build 1, x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30) of 2019-05-11.

This issue still persists when I run `emacs -Q` and I have tried adding `(add-hook 'isearch-update-post-hook 'redraw-display)` to my `init.el` file but this has not helped either.

Comment: You appear to be using a terminal emulator, though you don’t say which one. It is likely either a bug in your terminal emulator, or a misconfiguration. You might try a different terminal emulator (even just as a troubleshooting step), or you might prefer the Emacs GUI instead.

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs without an init file (`emacs -Q)`?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarity. I'm not so familiar with the terminology of emacs and I do not know which terminal emulator I am using. I have done no customization of emacs and am just running it with what I assume are the default settings. I'm under the impression that emacs is configured in ~/.emacs or ~/.emacs.d. I have added an ~/.emacs.d/init.el file to deal with reloading python modules in the python shell. Additionally there is a line about diff-switches in ~/.emacs. Otherwise these are empty. I am running emacs on a remote server and I have problems getting the GUI to run as well.

Comment: I do still see the issue running emacs -Q

Comment: You should run the Emacs GUI locally. Barring that, how do you log into the server?

Comment: I just ssh into the remote server. The server is an HPC with login nodes and compute nodes. For full clarity I get ```Display localhost:15.0 unavailable, simulating -nw``` when trying to use GUI Emacs on the compute nodes.

Comment: Sounds like you would need to use `ssh -X` to forward your X Windows connection to the server. But to get back to the terminal emulator, what program do you launch to open a command prompt when you ssh to the server?

Comment: I run the Terminal program on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.6. Sorry if this was what you were referencing in your first comment. I didn't realize exactly what terminal emulator meant.

Comment: Aha! That is very important information to include in your question. While you are at it, you should also specify what version of Emacs you are running.

Comment: Ok I added that info to the question. Thanks for the advice. Also I tried using iTerm2 instead and am still seeing the issue.